# how to use fireEvent to set selection in icCube

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

I have a multiselect filter widget with members of a demension to use it as a filter in my mdx. This works fine by use @{filter) in mdx. As if the filter is per user unique I want to store it in a database and load it if an user logs in. This works fine and getting the filter as a JSON object:

```
    data = [{
        "servicenumbers": [{
            "name": "+31880440723",
            "uniquename": "[Inkomend nummer].[Inkomend nummer].[Nummer].&[76]&[2308]"
        },
        {
            "name": "+31880440747",
            "uniquename": "[Inkomend nummer].[Inkomend nummer].[Nummer].&[76]&[2329]"
        },
        {
            "name": "+31880440758",
            "uniquename": "[Inkomend nummer].[Inkomend nummer].[Nummer].&[76]&[3670]"
        },
        {
            "name": "+31880440727",
            "uniquename": "[Inkomend nummer].[Inkomend nummer].[Nummer].&[76]&[2312]"
        }]
    }]
```

In my javascriptcode I have a "fireEvent" event to actually set the filter. code:

```
    function consumeEvent( context, event ) {                                
        var $report = context.$report;
        var fireEvent = context.fireEvent.bind(context);
        ... 
        some code
        ...

        fireEvent('filter',buildEvent(data));
    }
```

```
    function buildEvent(sel)
    {
     return {
            fireMdxByDefault: false,
            isGlobalFilter_: true,
            classID: viz.event.SetSelectionEvent,
            constructor: function w(A,B,z){x.call(this,B,z);this.classID="viz.event.SetSelectionEvent";this.selection=A},
            caption: function (){if(this.selection&&this.selection.length>0){return ic3.asMdxSet(this.selection,"name",false,true)}else{return""}},
            asMdx: function (){if(this.selection&&this.selection.length>0){return ic3.asMdxSet(this.selection,"uniqueName")}else{return null}},
            asFilterInitialSelection: function (){if(this.selection&&this.selection.length>0){return ic3.arrayProps(this.selection,"uniqueName")}else{return""}},
            getSelectedItems: function (){return this.selection},
            isSelectionEvent: function (){return true},
            isGlobalFilter: function (){return this.isGlobalFilter_},
            isEmptyEvent: function (){return false},
            value: function (){return this.asMdx()},
            asSet: function (){return this.asMdx().replace(/^\(/,"{").replace(/\)$/,"}")},
            asDefaultValue: function (){return this.asFilterInitialSelection()},
            asReportParam: function (){var H={};H.rpe=1;if(this.isEmptyEvent()){H.nil=true}else{var A=this.caption();if(A!==null){H.dft=A}var D=this.value();if(D!==null){H.val=D}var z=this.asMdx();if(z!==null){H.mdx=z}var x=this.asFilterInitialSelection();if(x!==null){H.fis=x}if(this.isSelectionEvent()){var B=this.getSelectedItems();if(B!==null){H.sel=B}}}return H},
            selection: sel.servicenumbers
        };  
    }
```

If I use "filter" in my MDX @{filter} the filter is applied in the query. But if I use it as a "do set Selection" in my filter widget it doesn't apply the selection and nothing is selected.

Does someone have a suggestion how to make this work?

Comment: What version of an icCube reporting you're using? You can find it under top menu "Admin" - "Version"

Comment: I'm using version: **icCube Reporting : 5.1.8 (6:2797)**